No module found 'azure' py2app poetry
I am wanting to build a tkinter based python program that uses azure speech sdk into a .dmg for the mac os. I am using Mac OS M3 Pro Sonoma.
In spite of confirming that the azure speech is installed in the environment and it is packaged properly using poetry when running the py2app build it fails, saying no module found 'azure'.
Can someone provide some insight as to how to fix py2app to look in correct directory for azure?
We can see that poetry finds the module:

poetry show azure-cognitiveservices-speech


name         : azure-cognitiveservices-speech
version      : 1.41.1
description  : Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK for Python

My setup.py is:
import sys
import os
import site
from typing import List, Dict, Any

APP_NAME: str = 'app'
VERSION: str = '1.0.0'
MIN_PYTHON_VERSION: str = '>=3.13'

REQUIRED_PACKAGES: List[str] = [
    'azure-cognitiveservices-speech>=1.41.1',
    'python-dotenv>=0.19.0',
]

SETUP_REQUIRES: List[str] = [
    'py2app',
    'setuptools>=44.0.0',
    'azure-cognitiveservices-speech>=1.41.1',
]

# Add Azure SDK import at module level with error handling
try:
    import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speech_sdk
    SPEECH_SDK_PATH = os.path.dirname(speech_sdk.__file__)
    AZURE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(SPEECH_SDK_PATH)))
except ImportError:
    SPEECH_SDK_PATH = None
    print("Warning: Azure Speech SDK not found. Build may be incomplete.")

def log_environment_info() -> None:
    """Log environment information for debugging purposes.
    
    Raises:
        ImportError: If azure speech SDK cannot be imported
    """
    print("Python interpreter being used:", sys.executable)
    print("Python path:", sys.path)
    print("Site packages:", site.getsitepackages())
    
    try:
        # List all files in the azure package directory
        azure_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(speech_sdk.__file__)))
        print("Contents of azure package directory:")
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(azure_dir):
            print(f"Directory: {root}")
            for file in files:
                print(f"  - {file}")
    except ImportError as e:
        print("Import Error:", str(e))
        raise

# Call this before setup()
log_environment_info()

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = [
    'requirements.txt',
    'settings.ini',
    '.venv',
    'languages.json',
]

# Get the site-packages directory and package paths
SITE_PACKAGES = site.getsitepackages()[0]
AZURE_PATH = os.path.join(SITE_PACKAGES, 'azure')
AZURE_SPEECH_PATH = os.path.join(SITE_PACKAGES, 'azure', 'cognitiveservices', 'speech')

OPTIONS: Dict[str, Any] = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': [
        'azure',
        'azure.cognitiveservices',
        'azure.cognitiveservices.speech',
    ],
    'packages': [
        'azure',
        'azure.cognitiveservices',
        'azure.cognitiveservices.speech',
    ],
    'site_packages': True,
    'resources': [
        AZURE_ROOT,  # Include the entire azure package
        SPEECH_SDK_PATH,  # Include the speech SDK specifically
    ],
    'frameworks': [],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'App',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleVersion': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleIdentifier': 'com.yourdomain.domain',
        'NSMicrophoneUsageDescription': 'test app',
        'LSMinimumSystemVersion': '10.10',
    }
}

setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=SETUP_REQUIRES,
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    python_requires=MIN_PYTHON_VERSION,
    description='Kasana Application',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='your.email@example.com',
    url='https://github.com/yourusername/app',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.13',
    ],
)

When py2app fails this is the part of the stack trace that seems to be the start of the failure. I've added the PACKAGE DIRECTORY to clearly delineate.
1120 total
42 filtered
150 orphaned
1078 remaining
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python311.zip/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/azure
PACKAGE DIRECTORY /Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_vendor/azure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/setup.py", line 135, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 117, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 183, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 199, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 999, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 973, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 987, in run
    self._run()
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1217, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1329, in run_normal
    pkgdirs = self.collect_packagedirs()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1293, in collect_packagedirs
    [
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1294, in <listcomp>
    os.path.join(os.path.realpath(self.get_bootstrap(pkg)), "")
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 2205, in get_bootstrap
    bootstrap = imp_find_module(bootstrap)[1]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/Code/Repos/kasana-production/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/modulegraph/util.py", line 34, in imp_find_module
    result = imp.find_module(name, path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/sethhammock/.pyenv/versions/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/imp.py", line 298, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named 'azure'```


Key Adjustments:
Explicitly set sys.path to include your virtual environment's site-packages directory.
Log environment details to help with debugging.
Adjust options to ensure all required packages are included.
Try running the build again after making these changes. If the issue persists, it may help to manually verify that the azure packages are correctly installed and accessible in your environment
import sys
import os
import site
from typing import List, Dict, Any
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

APP_NAME = 'app'
VERSION = '1.0.0'
MIN_PYTHON_VERSION = '>=3.13'

REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'azure-cognitiveservices-speech>=1.41.1',
    'python-dotenv>=0.19.0',
]

SETUP_REQUIRES = [
    'py2app',
    'setuptools>=44.0.0',
    'azure-cognitiveservices-speech>=1.41.1',
]

# Add Azure SDK import at module level with error handling
try:
    import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speech_sdk
    SPEECH_SDK_PATH = os.path.dirname(speech_sdk.__file__)
    AZURE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(SPEECH_SDK_PATH)))
except ImportError:
    SPEECH_SDK_PATH = None
    print("Warning: Azure Speech SDK not found. Build may be incomplete.")

def log_environment_info():
    """Log environment information for debugging purposes."""
    print("Python interpreter being used:", sys.executable)
    print("Python path:", sys.path)
    print("Site packages:", site.getsitepackages())
    
    try:
        azure_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(speech_sdk.__file__)))
        print("Contents of azure package directory:")
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(azure_dir):
            print(f"Directory: {root}")
            for file in files:
                print(f"  - {file}")
    except ImportError as e:
        print("Import Error:", str(e))
        raise

# Call this before setup()
log_environment_info()

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = [
    'requirements.txt',
    'settings.ini',
    '.venv',
    'languages.json',
]

# Get the site-packages directory and package paths
SITE_PACKAGES = site.getsitepackages()[0]
AZURE_PATH = os.path.join(SITE_PACKAGES, 'azure')
AZURE_SPEECH_PATH = os.path.join(SITE_PACKAGES, 'azure', 'cognitiveservices', 'speech')

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': [
        'azure',
        'azure.cognitiveservices',
        'azure.cognitiveservices.speech',
    ],
    'packages': [
        'azure',
        'azure.cognitiveservices',
        'azure.cognitiveservices.speech',
    ],
    'site_packages': True,
    'resources': [
        AZURE_ROOT,  # Include the entire azure package
        SPEECH_SDK_PATH,  # Include the speech SDK specifically
    ],
    'frameworks': [],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'App',
        'CFBundleShortVersionString': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleVersion': '1.0.0',
        'CFBundleIdentifier': 'com.yourdomain.domain',
        'NSMicrophoneUsageDescription': 'test app',
        'LSMinimumSystemVersion': '10.10',
    }
}

setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    packages=find_packages(),
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=SETUP_REQUIRES,
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    python_requires=MIN_PYTHON_VERSION,
    description='Kasana Application',
    long_description=open('README.md').read(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    author='Your Name',
    author_email='your.email@example.com',
    url='https://github.com/yourusername/app',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.13',
    ],
)


I pivoted to pyinstaller but the issue was the same. In pyinstaller it had to do with writing to the _MEI directory, which is a temporary directory. I wound up using the code below to solve the issue. Not Lee's issue above for poetry but the context is correct.
    # Get the directory of the current script
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

    # Construct the full path to the JSON file
    json_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'languages.json')

